# Select multiple files in Finder using the keyboard

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to select multiple files in a Finder window that are not consecutive. I know that since 10.6 one can do that by using the mouse + a combination of Shift and Cmd key. As a keyboard user I'm searching for a way to do that without the mouse. In Windows I hold Ctrl, use the Up/Down-arrow to navigate through the files, and finally select them using the Space bar. Is there an equivalent to that in MacOS X?

My MacOS X version is Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to make this work using "Mouse Keys" in the Accessibility preference pane in System Preferences. Works best with (might even require) a keyboard with a number pad. I am not sure that it will work for you but it is designed to allow someone to move the cursor and to click without using the mouse or trackpad but rather by the keys on the keypad.